# Suppress ESLint warnings in VSCode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, eslint

I am using ESLint [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint) in VSCode to format and check my JavaScript code. However, I don't want ESLint to show me warnings (red lines below code), esp. the ones related to code formatting, but still do the formatting every time I save the file. Is it possible to do this?

Here is my VSCode config:

```
{
  "editor.fontSize": 14,
  "explorer.openEditors.visible": 0,
  "files.autoSave": "onFocusChange",
  "terminal.integrated.fontSize": 14,
  "terminal.integrated.lineHeight": 1.3,
  "terminal.integrated.shell.osx": "zsh",
  "editor.codeLens": true,
  "editor.occurrencesHighlight": true,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": false
  },
  "eslint.enable": true,
  "eslint.autoFixOnSave": true,
  "eslint.alwaysShowStatus": false,
  "eslint.run": "onType",
  "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
  "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
  "diffEditor.ignoreTrimWhitespace": false
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should set your settings in the .eslintrc file (it can either be js, json, or yaml file, the best way to be sure you have the right file is to use the **"eslint --init"** command), Head into the "rules" sections and just add the name of the rule that you do not want to use, following by a comma and "0", for example:

```
"rules": {
    "no-inner-declarations": 0,
}
```

If you want to find the right settings name, you can stand with your mouse on the error indicated by esLint and the floating window that says what is the problem will contain the setting name.

you can also refer to this YouTube video for complete explanation:
[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cMrDePs86Uo](https://youtu.be/cMrDePs86Uo?t=337)

In the video it looks a bit different then now (I think this is an old version of VSCode) Today it looks like that:

[image: how to find the setting name in vsCode]

Also in case you did configure that and it still doesn't work I recommend you to start with a new small configuration file and step-by-step adding a new config each time and checking to see if it does not break the rest of the configurations.

This is my basic file that is working:

```
module.exports = {
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es6": true
    },
    "extends": "eslint:recommended",
    "globals": {
        "Atomics": "readonly",
        "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
    },
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        },
        "ecmaVersion": 2018,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "no-inner-declarations": 0,
    }
};
```

Comment: Did you follow the video?
Is the settings code that you pasted into the question is under the rules section?
Can you paste the full settings file?

Comment: I didn't find any mention of any setting that suppresses warnings in the video..can you point to the video duration where this is mentioned (if at all it's there..)?

Comment: I've edited the link to bring you to the direct location where he is talking about it, it's an old version of VSCode in the video so it looks a little bit different today

Comment: I've also added a picture of how it looks now

Comment: I think you did not get my question..setting `rules` to `"no-inner-declarations": 0` will only suppress warnings for variables and functions declared in inner scope. I want  to suppress ALL warnings that eslint can autofix like the ones regarding formatting code..I ONLY want it to show warnings for invalid JavaScript/JSX that will prevent the code from running in the browser.

Comment: I want to understand, so please answer these questions:
1. do you want to disable all coloring and warnings of eslint?
2. do you want to only use eslint for auto formatting?
3. do you want to have eslint fixing some problems without notifying you?

Maybe a solution for you can be to just add all the rules from the docs of eslint and set them to 0?
https://eslint.org/docs/rules/