# Remove squiggly lines from displaying for Prettier/ESlint

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

How to remove squiggly lines from showing on VS Code for ESlint & Prettier setup. I want ESlint to do its work, format and fix errors on save but don't want to see the squiggly lines. Not sure if its even possible as I couldn't find any info on this. Looks like Prettier is causing all the unwanted squiggly lines

Comment: The `workbench.colorCustomizations` called `editorError.border` and `editorError.foreground` can be set to match `editor.background`.  Of course, this will effectively render _all_ squigglies invisible, not just the ones from Prettier.

Comment: I've done something similar. Changed Prettier to display `warnings` instead of `errors` and then set the color of warnings to VS Code theme color. That way I still get proper warnings from everything else. I will still leave it open for answers as there might be a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

See [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37544897/1758461). You edit `settings.json` and set `"eslint.enable": false` in VS Code. There is an extension that does it too.

This disables it in VS Code. Then you run eslint as a background task using https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-watch or similar.

Comment: You haven't read the question properly. I want ESlint to keep working and fix errors and your suggestion disables all its functions

Comment: You run eslint as a build task in the background: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-watch

Comment: Maybe I haven't explain it very well. What I want is to make the squiggly lines disappear, not be visible or remove them altogether, like changing their color to match the background color. Don't need extra extensions or commands but just to make it less annoying while I code.

Comment: In that case, maybe a custom theme... but that is a lot of work. Most people would find it easier to disable it in the IDE and run it as a background task. I did some searching, and I fear you are right - it is not a common setup and doesn't seem supported. Closest thing I could find is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54761916/suppress-eslint-warnings-in-vscode).

Comment: I check the suggested article, added every single rule and set its value to 0 (as suggested), but still nothing. Then I realized it is all coming from Prettier ¯\_(ツ)_/¯